# Is there a way to import renpy directly in python instead of using renpy.exe?

Tags: python, renpy

I want to make a game in python that I can then import on an html page.
All in all, it's a visual novel with python games in it.
Is there a way to import the renpy library directly in python or should I do the opposite and import the python games in the renpy script?

```
import renpy
label start:

    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renpy isn't a python library so the answer is no, you can't.